# Mock function not being called in Jest/Enzyme test for React component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, antd

I'm dabbling with React testing with Jest and Enzyme, and am writing a simple test where I verify that two action creators are called with the correct arguments when the user inputs text into a search field. The user changing the input causes onChange and onSearch event handlers to fire (https://ant.design/components/select/).

I created mock functions for each of the action creators and set them as props to the component, which I shallow render. Problem is one of the mock functions is not being called upon simulating the input change, even though it does get called in the actual app.

Here are the relevant parts of the component:

```
export class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: '',
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
    this.handleSearch = _.debounce(this.handleSearch, 450);
  }

  handleChange(value) {
    this.setState({
      value,
    });
    this.props.setSearchSpinner(true);
  }

  handleSearch(value) {
    this.props.fetchVideos(value);
  }

  render() {
...
...
...
 return (
      <Select
        className="search-bar"
        mode="combobox"
        value={this.state.value}
        style={{ width: '100%', padding: '0 10px' }}
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        defaultActiveFirstOption={false}
        filterOption={false}
        notFoundContent={
          this.state.value !== '' ? 'we got nothin\' for you bruh' : null
        }
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onSearch={this.handleSearch}
      >
        {results}
      </Select>
    );
  }
}
```

and here's the test:

```
it("correctly calls fetchVideos with user's input", () => {
  const mockFetchVideos = jest.fn();
  const mockSetVideo = jest.fn();
  const mockSetSearchSpinner = jest.fn();
  const mockSetSearchPage = jest.fn();

  const wrapper = shallow(<SearchBar
    fetchVideos={mockFetchVideos}
    setVideo={mockSetVideo}
    setSearchSpinner={mockSetSearchSpinner}
    setSearchPage={mockSetSearchPage}
    placeholder="placeholder"
    currentResults={[]}
  />);

  const searchVal = 'mario';
  // simulate user typing 'mario' into search bar
  wrapper.find('.search-bar').simulate('change', {value: searchVal});
  // test to see arguments used after search has been submitted
  expect(mockSetSearchSpinner).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true);
  expect(mockFetchVideos).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

The test fails on the last line, so it looks like mockFetchVideos is not being called. I get this error:

```
FAIL  src/containers/search-bar.test.js
  ● correctly calls fetchVideos with user's input

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected mock function to have been called.

      at Object.<anonymous>.it (src/containers/search-bar.test.js:25:27)
          at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16)
          at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
```

I also tried creating a spy for the handleSearch method which contains fetchVideos, and testing whether that gets called. It doesn't get called either, so it seems like it's not a problem with mockFetchVideos, but rather with the change event not triggering handleSearch at all. I thought it may have something to do with the handleSearch being debounced, but removing the debounce didn't work either. What am I missing that is causing handleSearch to not be called?

Comment: You never trigger `onSearch` how should the `fetchVideos` be called. Also using `debounce` will make your test fail (https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3465). So I would suggest to mock it.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle Sorry if it wasn't clear, but I mentioned in my post that onSearch fires in the actual app when the input field is changed (https://ant.design/components/select/).

Comment: Still you need to trigger the event with enzyme. All `simulate` does is to call the function that is registered under the `on...` prop. So in your case only `this.handleChange` is called. Have a look at the common gotchas: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.md

Comment: @AndreasKöberle Hm okay, how would I trigger the event using enzyme then? I tried using `simulate` with "search" as the first argument but that doesn't appear to be valid.

Comment: In this case you have to do `.prop('onSearch')({value: searchVal})`.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle Thank you :)